# Excel Sheet in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application [asp.net], i am upload the Excel file from admin end. now i want to display that excel sheet in my asp.net at the user end whe he click on button "Show", is it possible to show the  uploaded excel sheet in asp.net pages. Tahnk you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about any third-party or open source control  but you may use [ADO.NET OleDB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311731) provider through which you can read excel sheet and later you may display content via `GridView` control.

Comment: Ok @AVD thank you for reply, but my client is asking like that only.